# Aspose PdfFileStamp headers overlapping

Tags: c#, aspose.pdf

I have recently upgraded my Aspose.Pdf library from 3.0.4.0 to 9.3.0.0. After the upgrade our use of the PdfFileStamp starting ignoring our margin options (top, left, right) and instead, writing all of the headers center aligned overlapping. (see image below for an example)

[image]

before, these headers were working to make the text appear as follows:
[image]

I am using a PdfFileStamp to add these headers:

```
PdfFileStamp fileStamp = new PdfFileStamp(pathToTempPdfFile, PathToPdf);
fileStamp.AddHeader(ftSite, 20, fileStamp.PageWidth / 2, fileStamp.PageWidth / 2);
fileStamp.AddHeader(ftVisit, 30, fileStamp.PageWidth / 2, fileStamp.PageWidth / 2);
fileStamp.AddHeader(ftGroup, 20, 0, 50);
fileStamp.AddHeader(ftForm, 30, 0, 50);
fileStamp.Save(pathToNewFile);
```

I tried placing each header item in their own file stamp, but that did not fix the issue.

**TL;DR:** why are my margin values in my header being ignored?

**UPDATE** I have added a github project with an example project showing this issue. it can be found here:
https://github.com/ntregillus/HeadersNotAligningCorrectly

Comment: added a request to aspose via their forums:
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/566156/multiple-header-and-footer-items-ignoring-margins-and-overlapping.aspx